# Bypass 'Hard blocked' wifi

Tags: 14.04, wireless, mate

Hi!

So I recently installed Ubuntu mate 14.04, but the wifi drivers broke after the install. Now the the wifi is hard block and I am unable to reactivate it. I do not have a wifi button nor a setting in the BIOS. Not even USB is working. Any ideas on how I can fix the wifi?

Sorry for not providing enough information on the problem. I am not really familiar with the wifi script you linked, but great tool, thank you for sharing :-)

Here is the output from the wifi script:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 04 Mar 2015 19:52 CET +0100

Booted last: 03 Mar 2015 22:08 CET +0100

Script from: 20 Sep 2014 23:04 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel ############################

Linux 3.13.0-39-generic #66-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 28 13:31:23 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

MATE

##### lspci #############################

06:05.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 2200BG [Calexico2] Network Connection [8086:4220] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation WM3B2300BG Mini-PCI Card [8086:2701]
    Kernel driver in use: ipw2200

06:07.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8100/8101L/8139 PCI Fast Ethernet Adapter [10ec:8139] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Wistron Corp. Device [17c0:1053]
    Kernel driver in use: 8139too

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 001 Device 006: ID 058f:6387 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Drive
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 07d1:3303 D-Link System DWA-131 802.11n Wireless N Nano Adapter(rev.A1) [Realtek RTL8192SU]
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes

##### lsmod #############################

r8712u                158706  0 
ipw2200               136401  0 
libipw                 33144  1 ipw2200
lib80211               14040  2 libipw,ipw2200
cfg80211              409394  2 libipw,ipw2200

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr   
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr   
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr   
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     unassociated  Nickname:"rtl_wifi"
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

eth1      IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Channel:0  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Bit Rate:0 kb/s   Tx-Power=off   Sensitivity=8/0  
          Retry limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface

##### resolv.conf #######################

##### nm-tool ###########################

NetworkManager Tool

State: disconnected

- Device: wlan0 ----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            r8712u
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        

  Capabilities:

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points 

- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            8139too
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off

- Device: eth1 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            ipw2200
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        

  Capabilities:

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points 

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Europe/Copenhagen (based on set time zone)

country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (3, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

eth0      no frequency information.

wlan0     14 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 14 : 2.484 GHz
eth1      11 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Current Channel=0

##### iwlist scan #######################

wlan0     Interface doesn't support scanning : Network is down

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

eth1      No scan results

##### module infos ######################

[r8712u]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-39-generic/kernel/drivers/staging/rtl8712/r8712u.ko
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8712u.bin
author:         Larry Finger
description:    rtl871x wireless lan driver
license:        GPL
srcversion:     5A7B13CC2FA1D2F4B5820F9
depends:        
staging:        Y
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-39-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 686 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        A6:96:31:EE:84:32:BD:22:00:4B:A4:DA:A9:78:CF:D9:2C:D5:5E:69
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           wifi_test:int
parm:           video_mode:int
parm:           chip_version:int
parm:           rfintfs:int
parm:           lbkmode:int
parm:           hci:int
parm:           network_mode:int
parm:           channel:int
parm:           mp_mode:int
parm:           wmm_enable:int
parm:           vrtl_carrier_sense:int
parm:           vcs_type:int
parm:           busy_thresh:int
parm:           ht_enable:int
parm:           cbw40_enable:int
parm:           ampdu_enable:int
parm:           rf_config:int
parm:           power_mgnt:int
parm:           low_power:int
parm:           ifname: Net interface name, wlan%d=default (string)
parm:           initmac:MAC-Address, default: use FUSE (charp)

[ipw2200]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-39-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ipw2x00/ipw2200.ko
firmware:       ipw2200-bss.fw
firmware:       ipw2200-sniffer.fw
firmware:       ipw2200-ibss.fw
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003-2006 Intel Corporation
version:        1.2.2kmprq
description:    Intel(R) PRO/Wireless 2200/2915 Network Driver
srcversion:     6432FDB1497A8B2EC025CB2
depends:        cfg80211,libipw,lib80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-39-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 686 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        A6:96:31:EE:84:32:BD:22:00:4B:A4:DA:A9:78:CF:D9:2C:D5:5E:69
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           disable:manually disable the radio (default 0 [radio on]) (int)
parm:           associate:auto associate when scanning (default off) (int)
parm:           auto_create:auto create adhoc network (default on) (int)
parm:           led:enable led control on some systems (default 1 on) (int)
parm:           debug:debug output mask (int)
parm:           channel:channel to limit associate to (default 0 [ANY]) (int)
parm:           rtap_iface:create the rtap interface (1 - create, default 0) (int)
parm:           qos_enable:enable all QoS functionalitis (int)
parm:           qos_burst_enable:enable QoS burst mode (int)
parm:           qos_no_ack_mask:mask Tx_Queue to no ack (int)
parm:           burst_duration_CCK:set CCK burst value (int)
parm:           burst_duration_OFDM:set OFDM burst value (int)
parm:           mode:network mode (0=BSS,1=IBSS,2=Monitor) (int)
parm:           bt_coexist:enable bluetooth coexistence (default off) (int)
parm:           hwcrypto:enable hardware crypto (default off) (int)
parm:           cmdlog:allocate a ring buffer for logging firmware commands (int)
parm:           roaming:enable roaming support (default on) (int)
parm:           antenna:select antenna 1=Main, 3=Aux, default 0 [both], 2=slow_diversity (choose the one with lower background noise) (int)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-39-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     C2478077E22138832B71659
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-39-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 686 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        A6:96:31:EE:84:32:BD:22:00:4B:A4:DA:A9:78:CF:D9:2C:D5:5E:69
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[r8712u]
ampdu_enable: 1
busy_thresh: 40
cbw40_enable: 1
channel: 1
chip_version: 2
hci: 1
ht_enable: 1
ifname: wlan%d
initmac: (null)
lbkmode: 0
low_power: 0
mp_mode: 0
network_mode: 0
power_mgnt: 0
rf_config: 1
rfintfs: 2
vcs_type: 1
video_mode: 1
vrtl_carrier_sense: 2
wifi_test: 0
wmm_enable: 0

[ipw2200]
antenna: 0
associate: 0
auto_create: 1
bt_coexist: 0
burst_duration_CCK: 0
burst_duration_OFDM: 0
channel: 0
cmdlog: 0
debug: 0
disable: 0
hwcrypto: 0
led: 1
mode: 0
qos_burst_enable: 0
qos_enable: 0
qos_no_ack_mask: 0
roaming: 1
rtap_iface: 0

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

lp

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac
blacklist iwl3945

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8139 (8139too)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
# PCI device 0x8086:0x4220 (ipw2200)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth1"
# USB device 0x:0x (r8712u)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

##### dmesg #############################

[ 1142.900335] r8712u 1-3:1.0 wlan0: Suspending...
[ 1142.900337] r8712u 1-3:1.0 wlan0: Unable to suspend
[ 1142.942808] eth1: Going into suspend...
[ 1143.115645] ipw2200: Unable to load ucode: -22
[ 1143.115652] ipw2200: Unable to load firmware: -22
[ 1143.115653] ipw2200: Failed to up device
[ 1143.733673] eth1: Coming out of suspend...
[ 1143.897886] ipw2200: Radio Frequency Kill Switch is On:
[ 1143.897886] Kill switch must be turned off for wireless networking to work.
[ 1146.831321] r8712u: Staging version
[ 1146.831351] r8712u: register rtl8712_netdev_ops to netdev_ops
[ 1146.831357] usb 1-2: r8712u: USB_SPEED_HIGH with 4 endpoints
[ 1146.831812] usb 1-2: r8712u: Boot from EFUSE: Autoload OK
[ 1147.349204] usb 1-2: r8712u: CustomerID = 0x0000
[ 1147.349213] usb 1-2: r8712u: MAC Address from efuse = 
[ 1147.349217] usb 1-2: r8712u: Loading firmware from "rtlwifi/rtl8712u.bin"
[ 1148.716173] ipw2200: Failed to send POWER_MODE: Command timed out.
[ 1148.716650] systemd-udevd[2796]: renamed network interface wlan1 to wlan0
[ 1148.805856] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready

########## wireless info END ############
```

- Sebbe

Comment: have you tried disconnecting/reconnecting the wifi card itself ? Hard Block really refers to hardware side of things.

Comment: Pleas [run the WiFi diagnostics](/q/425155) and [edit] your question to include a link to the results.

Answer (score 0):

```
[ 1143.897886] ipw2200: Radio Frequency Kill Switch is On:
[ 1143.897886] Kill switch must be turned off for wireless networking to work.
```

According to the [forum posts](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=964956) you can try reinserting the module for your wireless card

`sudo rmmod -v ipw2200 && sleep2 && sudo modprobe ipw2200`

Also , remove line `&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211` from `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` file

Comment: I am sorry say that this did not fix the problem. The hardware blockage persists :/